# how to add br between attributes item woocommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

hi everyone i want to try add 
 tag on the attributes item woocommerce to show any item per line .
can i help me to do that?
here is my product-attributes.php file code

```
<table class="woocommerce-product-attributes shop_attributes">
<?php foreach ( $product_attributes as $product_attribute_key => $product_attribute ) : ?>
    <tr class="woocommerce-product-attributes-item woocommerce-product-attributes-item--<?php echo esc_attr( $product_attribute_key ); ?>">
        <th class="woocommerce-product-attributes-item__label"><?php echo wp_kses_post( $product_attribute['label'] ); ?></th>
        <td class="woocommerce-product-attributes-item__value"><?php echo wp_kses_post( $product_attribute['value'] ); ?></td>
    </tr>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can try below code for example:

```
<table class="woocommerce-product-attributes shop_attributes">
<?php foreach ( $product_attributes as $product_attribute_key => $product_attribute ) : ?>
    <tr class="woocommerce-product-attributes-item woocommerce-product-attributes-item--<?php echo esc_attr( $product_attribute_key ); ?>">
        <th class="woocommerce-product-attributes-item__label"><?php echo wp_kses_post( $product_attribute['label'] ); ?></th>
        <td class="woocommerce-product-attributes-item__value"><?php echo str_replace(',','<br>',wp_kses_post( $product_attribute['value'] )); ?></td>
    </tr>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

I didn't check on a real project. let me know if it works or not.

Answer (score 0):

Please try following code and check if it's working.

```
<table class="woocommerce-product-attributes shop_attributes">
<?php foreach ( $product_attributes as $product_attribute_key => $product_attribute ) : ?>
<tr class="woocommerce-product-attributes-item woocommerce-product-attributes-item--<?php echo esc_attr( $product_attribute_key ); ?>">
    <th class="woocommerce-product-attributes-item__label"><?php echo wp_kses_post( $product_attribute['label'] ); ?></th>
    <td class="woocommerce-product-attributes-item__value"><?php echo wp_kses_post( $product_attribute['value'] ).'<br>'; ?></td>
</tr>
```